# css for hiding elements on pages that load for check-in

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-online, 2016

I added a footer in masterpage

Now when I try to check-in any item, the buttons are hidden by the footer

How can I hide for such pages alone?

I noticed that all such iframes have a parameter `&IsDlg=1` and SharePoint hides elements based on that. How can I add footer to those elements?

I tried  adding this in console but it is not hiding the footer

```
.ms-dlgFrame footer {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: You want hide footer in those `isDlg` pages ?

Comment: yeah that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add below css in your footer :

```
footer .s4-notdlg {display:none;}
```

Or in your html tag as below:

```
<footer class="s4-notdlg">
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm
btw should I reframe the question? is there a specific term for pages like check-in?

Comment: I think its fine by me now :)